# Why my Angular setup not Loading

Tags: angularjs

Here i try to Angular setup  in html page for that i wrote simple code as Below

**MyApp.js**

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
debugger;
app.controller('HomeCtrls', function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "This is MyApp....";
})
```

**Master.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head ng-app="MyApp">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/MyApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HomeCtrls">
    {{msg}}
</body>
</html>
```

Here why my msg is not Loading This is MyApp....

Comment: is there any errors in the console

Comment: no error its just display as {{msg}}

Comment: make sure your script files are loading. go to browser console and check the network tab

Comment: all these are loading in  networktab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-app inject wrong place. Not `<head ng-app="MyApp">`, Inject `html or body or div` tag as per your web application need.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/MyApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrls">
    {{msg}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's a nice catch!

Comment: Welcome @Joe Pill

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your angular script, is not loaded, check your path, you can use the CDN also :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```